# Using an if statement to check if a date is more than a year c#

Tags: c#

```
  var carID = taxBDO.Customer_Id;
  Customer customerInDb = (from p in TaxEnitites.Customers
                           where p.Customer_Id == carID
                           select p).FirstOrDefault();

  if (customerInDb.Date_Taxed < 365)
  {

  }
```

I have retrieve a date from my db that I have set up, however I can not figure out to use an if statement t use this date from my database to check if this date is more that a year ago,

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add negative one years to today and compare:

```
customerInDb.Date_Taxed < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
```

Comment: Do not forget to check `customerInDb` for `null` before this.

Comment: I have done this now but everytime I run the wcf test client it is always coming back true even when I have entered data in the database that is previous to year

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can compute a timespan between now and then and fetch the total number of days.

`DateTime.Now.Subtract(customerInDb.Date_Taxed).TotalDays > 365`

Comment: @Crowcoder might have a slightly better answer when considering a date that would span a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

Crowcoder has already given a solution which will work in most cases.

But, `dateTime.Now` has the `Time` component as well! So, if

```
customerInDb.Date_Taxed = {15/11/2014 00:05:30}
DateTime.Now = {15/11/2015 00:22:30}
```

Then

```
Date_Taxed < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) => true
```

Though it's on the same date last year. And this calculation will depend on the current time, so you'll get different results at different time of the day.

If you want this, then fine. Else, you can compare just the **`Date`** part as

```
var isMoreThanYearAgo = customerInDb.Date_Taxed.Date < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Date;
```

Also, check `customerInDb` for `null` before you call this, as you are getting this as a result of `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: This is a great point. "A year ago" can be different things depending on desired behavior.